# Get elements that do not have a certain sibling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to find text areas that do not have a sibling of a certain class. Currently I am using the following:

```
$("textarea").not($("textarea").siblings(".siblingClass").siblings("textarea"))
```

Is there an alternative?

Sorry for the lack of context. The problem I am having is that I have a jquery plugin (maxlength) that runs multiple times (due to dynamic changes) and adds a div after textareas. The plugin does not check if it has already been run, so it will add the div multiple times.

Comment: Can you give a little more context? I mean some HTML. Are there parent containers?

Comment: Might be easier to fix the serverside code to add a class that has this situation. Please share some HTML so we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: If siblings are guaranteed to be following the textarea you can use selector like 'textarea ~ :not(.siblingClass)' otherwise a filter like answers below will do it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) can be useful.

```
$('textarea').filter(function(){
  return $(this).siblings('.that-class').length == 0;
});
```

```js
$('textarea').filter(function(){
  return $(this).siblings('.a').length == 0;
}).css( "color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <textarea>one</textarea>
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <textarea>two</textarea>
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea>three</textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <textarea>four</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```